# How to configure BentoML docker container to write log messages to a file in a mounted dir?

Tags: bentoml

I'm not able to configure BentoML logs to be written in a mounted directory in my docker container.

The [BentoML Logging documentation](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/latest/guides/logging.html) shows no parameter to write the logs to a file.

The [Legacy property mapping doc page](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/0.13-lts/guides/configuration.html#legacy-property-mapping) talks about a log dir, but if I try to put these properties in the bento_configuration.yml or bentofile.yml the tool complains that the properties are invalid.

I've also tried to configure Python logging from my bento_service.py file, but some info are still written to the Docker console log.

Where can find a BentoML configuration example that writes all log messages from the docker console to a file?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the given example: [1. Basic Logging Configuration](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/0.13-lts/guides/logging.html#)? It should output logs at INFO level both to console and file.

Comment: Yes. This is from from version 0.13. It complains that the parameter logging.fine does not exist. Current bentoml version is 0.20